# Written Signature on Application in c# MVC3 (non hosted) as part of Employment Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, digital-signature

I'm trying to find a solution similar to http://www.tenstreet.com .  I've tried looking around the internet and on sourceforge, but everything I find is about a cryptography digital signature (which I'll be using, but not what I'm lacking), not the image digital signature.  I've found plenty of hosted solutions, but due to the nature of our business a hosted solution is not possible (where I work EVERYTHING pretty much must be done internal).

Just in case this doesn't make sense I'll explain the background.  We are a trucking company and part of our driver application is a signature release form.  We are currently required to fax that form out get the signature and wait for it to be faxed back.  What we are looking to accomplish is have this process be 100% digital an on our website.  Lastly, legality wise our legal department has that worked out, I just have to source the technology and I'm having trouble finding it.

The technologies in use are C# MVC3 (Razor View Engine)/JavaScipt/jQuery/jQuery UI/HTML5 markup is in use.  If you need any other information please let me know!

Comment: Interesting question, though when I tried to do my signature with the mouse I couldn't get it to look much like my handwritten signature.

Comment: Luckily this doesn't change the fact that it's legally binding!!!

Comment: Well the other day I signed my daughter out of an after-school activity by putting an "X" in the signature box (though I did print my name and the time in the appropriate boxes). Anyway, sorry I can't actually help with your problem beyond mentioning a site I found by googling "signature with mouse": http://www.onlinesignaturepad.com/ - requires Silverlight, so is I suppose the MS equivalent of a Flash or Shockwave based solution.

Comment: @nnnnnn will you please post that comment as an answer so I can accept it?  This was something like I was looking for so would like to give you credit. -Jared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something with an HTML5 canvas, though I don't think IE supports it until IE9. But there are a number of HTML5 canvas drawing tutorials around, including [the one at dev.opera.com](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/), and there are canvas-based components like [paintweb](http://code.google.com/p/paintweb/).

By googling "signature with mouse" I found this site: http://www.onlinesignaturepad.com - requires Silverlight, so is I suppose the MS equivalent of a Flash or Shockwave based solution. The search returned some other options, so perhaps one or another will suite your project.

Answer (score 2):

Little Late, but at this time I'd use :

[JQuery Signature Pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/)

and

Server Side C#:

[Signature to Image Github (C#)](https://github.com/parrots/SignatureToImageDotNet)