# .NET: how to develop function that user can use mouse do a electronic signature?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I wonder how to write function that people could use their mouse to sign on the web form. Like I set a small area on the web form, user could sign in it using mouse. So they don't have to print it out and the signature will be saved as an image(i'm not sure either)?

Comment: That would probably be very insecure! I highly recommend using a daily, testet approach like a password over SSL (HTTPS). Or maybe a certificate for the user to authenticate if it should be something fancy ...

Comment: What purpose should that "signature" serve? Be aware that such kind of "signatures" won't have any legal value. If that is required you most likely would have to implement a solution involving qualified electronic signatures, e.g. using smart cards.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7947472/615754? HTML5 Canvas, Silverlight or Flash/Shockwave are all options. See also http://www.onlinesignaturepad.com

Comment: There is no way I can write my signature with the _mouse_...

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can:

- implement a [basic HTML5 canvas drawing app](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/).
- export the drawing from the canvas as a base64 string ([Canvas API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement), [toDataURL()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl)).
- convert the base64 string to an image on your server using back-end scripts.
  check out the [.NET-based solution](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is called "esign".

There are several companies that do this.  I can't recall the name of one I worked with a few years ago, but one I just found is at [www.echosign.com](http://www.echosign.com)

(I'm not affiliated with them)